# Hacer conexión de Visual Studio a Base de datos sql web

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Como puedo estableces una conexión desde visual studio a una base de datos que este en un host web? Por ejemplo Awardspace.

***En Resumen***

Quiero hacer una conexión con una base de datos externa a visual studio. 
Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Para eso no creo que sea necesario preguntar en SO, google tiene muchas guías y ejemplos

Comment: Ya busque muchas veces, no encontré respuesta, como ultimo recurso pregunte aquí. Saludos.

Comment: Igual no está muy clara tu duda. Cuando dices "desde Visual Studio" ¿te refieres a conectarte a un servidor de base de datos desde el entorno de desarrollo o desde código en c#?  ¿a que tipo de servidor te quieres conectar? ¿MySql? ¿Sql Server? ¿Es servidor remoto (por internet), en red loca o en el. mismo pcl?

Comment: Prácticamente la formule algo mal, lo que quiero hacer es eso, lo que no me exprese muy bien y no lo puse textual ni entendible es, que quiero también saber si se puede, y ya me respondieron esa duda.

Answer (score 0):

cómo estás?

La conexión se debe realizar de la misma manera que si estuviera en tu red local, usando una dominio (como mibase.midominio.com) o dirección IP, pero tienes que asegurarte que el servidor de base de datos esté público, o sea, que acepte conexiones desde el exterior.  Algunos hostings no dejan que te conectes desde afuera, sino que en su lugar tienen alguna herramienta web de administración de la base de datos.

Saludos.